# Unexpected Visual C++ linker behavior regarding function exports, when an inline function is involved

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, inline

We build a static library with Visual C++ (version 15 is used), and this library that has the following functions:

```
extern "C" void __stdcall Internal()
{
...
}

class SomeClass {
  inline void SomeFunc()
  {
    Internal(); // calling Internal here
  }
}
```

When this static library is linked to an EXE, Internal gets exported from the EXE (i.e., one can see Internal in the EXE's exports). If we make SomeFunc not inline, Internal doesn't get exported.

Does anybody know why the "inline" modifier has an effect of an undesired export being generated?